# Standard compliant custom allocator

Tags: c++, allocator

Is OK to throw an exception when 0 is passed to `allocate` method?

Thank you.

P.S.

> If n == 0, the return value is
>   unspecified.

Does it mean that `allocate` shouldn't throw an exception? I am inclined to think that if throwing wasn't allowed for n==0, then the standard would clearly spell it out.

Comment: It is not standard compliant for the allocator to throw an exception on a zero length allocation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All the standard has to say (§20.1.5/2) is that given

- `T` – any type
- `X` – an *Allocator* class for type `T`
- `a` – a value of type `X&`
- `n` – a value of type `X::size_type`,

the return value of the expression `a.allocate(n)` is *unspecified* if `n` equals 0.

One one hand, given that `X::allocate` doesn't have any mandated exception specification and explicitly *may* throw `std::bad_alloc`, I don't see why it couldn't throw some other type of exception as well. On the other hand, the wording specifically calls out the condition wherein `n` equals zero and directly implies that there *is* a return value, meaning you *shouldn't* throw. I think it may be open to some interpretation, but personally I'd side with the latter and consider it an unexceptional code-path.

Comment: Thanks. I knew that that the return value is unspecified for n == 0, but wasn't sure about throwing an exception.

Answer (score 5):

The standard demands that an allocation of size `0` shall return a pointer to a memory block of `1` byte size, Brb, looking for relevant standards paragraph.

---

**Edit**:
First, I only got the FDIS of C++0x/11 handy (not at home...), but I believe the wording was similar in C++98/03.

Next, it seems I was wrong. It is nowhere stated that the allocator shall return a memory block of size `1`. My memory served me wrong. :( Though, I found this little paragraph under 3.7.4.2 [basic.stc.dynamic.allocation] p2:

> Even if the size of the space requested is zero, the request can fail. If the request succeeds, the value returned shall be a non-null pointer value (4.10) p0 different from any previously returned value p1, unless that value p1 was subsequently passed to an operator delete. The effect of dereferencing a pointer returned as a request for zero size is undefined.**<sup>35)</sup>**

At the end of the same site:

> **35)** The intent is to have operator new() implementable by calling std::malloc() or std::calloc(), so the rules are substantially
>   the same. **C++ differs from C in requiring a zero request to return a non-null pointer.**

(Emphasis mine.)

Now, the FDIS says under `17.6.3.5` [allocator.requirements], in a note on `allocate`:

```
a.allocate(n)     X::pointer
```

> Memory is allocated for `n` objects of type `T` but objects are not constructed. `allocate` may raise an appropriate exception. **[ Note: If n == 0, the return value is unspecified. —end note ]**

(Emphasis mine.)
So, you shall not throw, as a return of *something* is implied by that note. It is, however, not required to return a `1` byte sized memory block. So, to answer your question: No, you are not allowed to throw in `allocate` when the size request is `0` when implementing a standard compliant allocator.

Comment: Kind of right... the standard does not sanction throwing an exception, but it does not require returning a block of memory either. In particular in Table 32 - Allocator requirements in section 20.1.5 - Allocator requirements, the description of `allocate(n) / allocate(n,u) has a note: *[Note: if n==0, the return value is unspecified]*, so a conforming implementation can return a block of 1 byte, or a null pointer or basically any other thing as long as it is documented by the compiler vendor.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez: Does it need to be sanctioned? The standard doesn't mention it either way but `Allocator::allocate` can already throw and `Allocator::allocate` doesn't have an exception specification.

Comment: @David: I think I took to long searching the standard. >_>"

Comment: @Xeo : It happens; I never knew that about `malloc` in C++ (since I never use it), so +1 anyway. :-P

Comment: @ildjarn: Edited again, with the relevant standard paragraph on the note I found.

Comment: @Xeo : That applies only to `operator new` though, not to standard allocators, no?

Comment: @ildjarn: It applies to allocation functions, it's not specified which, but I believe it means global allocation functions like `malloc` and `calloc`, though it really could mean all of them, since all of them fulfill the requirements mentioned there. You should read through it yourself. :)

Comment: @Xeo : I did read it; it says "*A C++ implementation provides access to, and management of, **dynamic storage** via the global **allocation functions `operator new` and `operator new[]`** and the global deallocation functions `operator delete` and `operator delete[]`.*" and the reference section name is "_[basic.stc. **dynamic.allocation** ]_", so I think it only applies to `new` and `new[]`.

Comment: @ildjarn: On whether it can / should throw, I am no expert when it comes to that part of the standard, and I understood *the return value is unspecified* as there has to be a return value, which in the case of an exception would not be the case. Rereading the same block (this time less tired, and not coming from a bar) it does allow for exceptions to be thrown in allocate: *Memory is allocated for n objects of type T but objects are not constructed. allocate may raise an appropriate exception. The result is a random access iterator [Note: if n==0, the return value is unspecified]*

Comment: Now, going around other parts of the standard, I have just found out that you are right. In  3.7.3.1/2, dealing with allocation functions (not exactly allocators, but I guess that both model the same problem) the standard is explicit in that a request for 0 size memory *can* fail (i.e. throw exception if the exception specification is not empty): *Even if the size of the space requested is zero, the request can fail.* The whole paragraph is too long to copy here.